# Invalid token when executing a query on a contentfeed in google sites when using Oath

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-apps, google-sites

I am trying to get this to work. It works fine when I use the client login method (username/password) but with oath it does not work. I would like to know why.

I am using this piece of code from [Java Language Guide (v1.4)](http://code.google.com/apis/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_java.html#ContentFeedQueriesPath)

> Retrieving a page by path
>
> If you know the relative path of a page within the Google Site, you
>   can use the path parameter to fetch that particular page. This example
>   would return the page located at
>   http://sites.google.com/site/siteName/path/to/the/page:

```
ContentQuery query = new ContentQuery(new URL(buildContentFeedUrl()));
query.setPath("/path/to/the/page");
ContentFeed contentFeed = client.getFeed(query, ContentFeed.class);
for (BaseContentEntry<?> entry : contentFeed.getEntries()) {
  System.out.println(" title: " + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
}
```

If I use the client login method everything works fine. However when I use Oath (Two-legged) I get the following response:

```
com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Token invalid - Invalid token:
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Token invalid - Invalid token: </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Token invalid - Invalid token: </H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This version works fine:

```
SitesService client = new SitesService("Test");
client.setUserCredentials(USER_NAME, PASSWORD);

ContentQuery query = new ContentQuery(new URL(
    "https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/" + DOMAIN + "/" + SITE_NAME + "/"));

query.setPath("/7D502A5D7080697F65F838D56C4C4A09");
ContentFeed contentFeed = client.getFeed(query, ContentFeed.class);
for (BaseContentEntry entry : contentFeed.getEntries()) {
    System.out.println("Title: " + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
}
```

And this version throws the error:

```
SitesService client = new SitesService("Test");
GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
oauthParameters.setScope("https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/");
client.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());

ContentQuery query = new ContentQuery(new URL(
    "https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/" + DOMAIN + "/" + SITE_NAME + "/"
    + "?xoauth_requestor_id=" + USER_NAME));


query.setPath("/7D502A5D7080697F65F838D56C4C4A09");
ContentFeed contentFeed = client.getFeed(query, ContentFeed.class);
for (BaseContentEntry entry : contentFeed.getEntries()) {
    System.out.println("Title: " + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
}
```

I also noticed that when I remove the line:

```
query.setPath("/7D502A5D7080697F65F838D56C4C4A09");
```

The error is not thrown, but obviously it will return all the pages in the site.

Answer (score 0):

Is your site is public? or do you enabled PAGE LEVEL PERMISSIONS and that particular page has limited number of people to have view/edit access?
This may be the reason.